# Software for recombining two dvd iso's

Tags: linux, dvd, iso-image, arch-linux

I have two DVD's which I converted into two iso files.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to combine the two DVD's into one, but I also need to cut out a part of one DVD.

The question is if anyone knows a good application that can solve this problem or a part of it.

I've already tried Avidemux, and although it seems it fitted my needs, it crashes when opening one of the isos (cryptic assertion error). I've also tried several others, but for some reason don't want to run or compile. (kdenlive misses a shared libery, while lives [fails](https://gist.github.com/739e947388e697551a60) to compile).

So my question is if anyone knows something that can do this.

Comment: Just extract the contents of the iso using any program like WinZip and/or 7-zip into two folders. Copy the contents you want into a third folder then create the iso from that data.  This general suggestion should still be valid for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

**Step One**

Rip the discs onto the hard drive.  Get and install Ripping software.  Doesn't matter.  Whatever works for you, but [here are 5 to choose from](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-dvd-ripper-software.html).  You know... mount the ISOs, rip them, unmount the ISOs.

**Step Two**

Edit and re-encode the ripped files to something that will only take up half of a disc each.  Why?  Because each movie will take up most of a disc... and you need to fit two onto one DVD.  That, and you say you need to edit.  That's where AVIDemux comes in.  After you have ripped the files off the ISOs, then you edit them.  Hell, you can use at least one ripping tool to re-encode to a smaller bitrate for one of the movies (like, 5000kbps to 2500kbps... just as an example).  So, don't use AVIDemux on the ISO... use it on the ripped VOB files after you pull them from the ISO.

**Step Three**

Use something like [DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/) to author the new DVD ISO.  Or even use a program like [DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) with [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: If you're having to edit the content of the videos anyways, this is the way to go. If the content is video (as opposed to data), this is the only way to go. Oh, and I used DVD Flick recently to build a DVD. Worked great and is highly reviewed on LifeHacker.

Comment: @music2myear he's using Linux, and DVD Flick is Windows only... but there are definitely other free authoring programs available, other than DVD Styler I agree.

Comment: You're right. I'd forgotten that point by the time I got down to the comment SQUIRREL!

Comment: @music2myear actually though... (edit)

Comment: I'm curious how much the quality will degrade when ripping (encode #1), cutting and merging (encode #2) and authoring (encode #3).

Comment: Ripping just moves the vob files without loss.  Re-encoding will see a drop in quality, but that is to be expected with putting two movies on one disc.  If the mpeg format is kept throughout the process and you re-encode to the righr bitrate, there is no loss when reauthoring.